# How can I reformat an image with MATLAB

Tags: image, matrix, reformatting

I have **27** (n) images with size **128x128** (m). I need to reformat the images as an **n x m**  matrix (27x16384).

I am working with  MATLAB 
and the only solution that I found is to organize them as **128x3456** or **3456x128**.

Comment: Your description is a bit difficult to understand. Are you saying that you have a `128x128x27` matrix that you want to reshape to `27x16384`?

Comment: yes please ,but without using reshape

Comment: Why do you not want to use `reshape`? Does it give the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the images into 27 column vectors, and then transpose:

```
m = 128; n = 128; p = 27;
images = rand(m, n, p);

row_images = reshape(images, m*n, p).';
```

The resulting matrix will then have the proper dimensions:

```
>> size(row_images)
ans =
      27   16384
```

Comment: thank you ,but with reshape ,all the information in the image is changed

Comment: No information is changed, it is simply reordered. If you want the information in a different order, you will have to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: @hajer What information do you think is changed by `reshape`? Do you have an example?